# what is meaning of (model!=null) and (db!=null) in this context

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

```
public bool SetupEmpty(UserViewModel model, SimsContext db)
{
    if (model != null && db != null)
    {
        // Setup the User
        model.User = new T2.Models.User();
        model.User.Roles = "";
        model.User.ActiveUser = true;

    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: well we have no "context" about what this question is, so all we can deduce is that your code is checking if an object exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking that both model and db have been set before starting to use them. Otherwise, if one of them is not set the program could crash.

Comment: so u mean  userviewmodel model =new userviewmodel;

Comment: Yes, both model and db will have to have been instantiated. If model is null, and we try to do model.User, we'll get a NullReferenceException. It doesn't make sense to access properties of an object that doesn't exist. On a side note, it's slightly confusing that the db variable is never actually used.